# Poor performance comparing collections of objects using reflections and Linq Except/Intersect

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have written an app which compares two collections of objects (of the same type) and works out the similarities and the differences by comparing the objects using values of their properties (or combinations of their properties). This app was never intended to scale above 10000 objects in either of the collections and it was accepted that this a long running operation. The business requirement has now changed and we need to be able to compare up to 50000 (with a stretch target of up to 100000) of objects in either of the collections.

Below is minimal example of a type to be compared.

```
    internal class Employee
    {
        public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
    }
```

For this purpose I have written a custom equality comparer for this type which takes a property name as a constructor parameter. Reason for parameterizing this was to avoid writing different equality comparers for each property of each type (which were was a fair amount and also this sounded like a neat solution).

```
   public class EmployeeComparerDynamic : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
    {
        string PropertyNameToCompare { get; set; }
        public EmployeeComparerDynamic(string propertyNameToCompare)
        {
            PropertyNameToCompare = propertyNameToCompare;
        }

        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return y.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetValue(y) != null 
                && x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetValue(x)
                .Equals(y.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetValue(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee x) 
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this equality comparer I have been comparing collections of objects using LINQ `Intersect` and `Except` functions.

```
        var intersectingEmployeesLinq = firstEmployeeList
            .Intersect(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerDynamic("ReferenceCode")).ToList();

        var deltaEmployeesLinq = firstEmployeeList
            .Except(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerDynamic("ReferenceCode")).ToList();
```

This was all working nicely until the scaling limit requirement increased and I have noticed that my app is performing very poorly with large collections of objects.

Initially, I thought that this is just normal and there is likely to be a significant increase in the overall time to complete, however, when I've tried looping through one list manually and comparing the item to check if such item exists in the other list - I have noticed that my own implementation of what LINQ `Except` and `Intersect` achieves in the context of my app is yielding the same results, but performing a lot better.

```
        var intersectingEmployeesManual = new List<Employee>();           

        foreach (var employee in firstEmployeeList)
        {
            if (secondEmployeeList.Any(x => x.ReferenceCode == employee.ReferenceCode))
                intersectingEmployeesManual.Add(employee);
        }
```

This was performing significantly better (about 30 times) compared to the implementation in the earlier snippet. Of course, the earlier snippet used reflection to get the value of the property, so I also tried that.

```
        var intersectingEmployeesManual = new List<Employee>();

        foreach (var employee in firstEmployeeList)
        {
            if (secondEmployeeList.Any(x => x.GetType()
                .GetProperty("ReferenceCode").GetValue(x)
                .Equals(employee.GetType().GetProperty("ReferenceCode").GetValue(employee))))
                intersectingEmployeesManual.Add(employee);
        }
```

This was still performing  about 2-3 times better. Lastly, I have then wrote another equality comparer, but instead of parameterizing the property, it was comparing against a predefined property of a type.

```
    public class EmployeeComparerManual : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
    {
        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return y.ReferenceCode != null
                   && x.ReferenceCode.Equals(y.ReferenceCode);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee x)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + x.ReferenceCode.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the corresponding code to work out the intersection and the delta objects.

```
        var intersectingEmployeesLinqManual = firstEmployeeList
            .Intersect(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerManual()).ToList();

        var deltaEmployeesLinqManual = firstEmployeeList
            .Except(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerManual()).ToList();
```

Finally, I started getting the scaling that I was looking for with this implementation, but additionally I have done some benchmarking using 10 different machines. The results are as per below (averaged, in milliseconds rounded to the nearest millisecond).

```
    +-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+--------+----------------+----------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
    |       | List Items  | Intersect | Intersect Dynamic | Except | Except Dynamic | Intersect Linq | Intersect Linq Dynamic | Except Linq | Except Linq Dynamic |
    +-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+--------+----------------+----------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
    | Run 1 | 5000/4000   |       479 |              7440 |    340 |           7439 |              1 |                  14583 |           2 |               15257 |
    | Run 2 | 10000/8000  |      2177 |             32489 |   1282 |          29290 |              1 |                  59154 |           2 |               74170 |
    | Run 3 | 20000/16000 |      6758 |            116266 |   4578 |         116720 |              5 |                 225960 |           3 |              295146 |
    | Run 4 | 50000/40000 |     34457 |            720023 |  30693 |         731690 |             14 |                1483084 |          14 |             1657832 |
    +-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+--------+----------------+----------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

So, my summary so far is:

- Using reflections to get the value of a property adds overhead with a factor between 15-20
- Using reflections in the equality comparer and LINQ `Except` or `Intersect` adds overhead with a factor of 2-3

My outstanding questions are:

- Is using reflection to get the value of property really adds that much overhead or am I missing a piece of a puzzle here?
- Why am I only getting the promised O(n+m) overall effort when using LINQ with an equality comparer which does not use reflection?
- Is there a hope for me to find and approach where I can have an equality comparer per type and somehow parameterize the property I am comparing by instead of an equality comparer per type per property?
- *Side question - Why using reflections in the equality comparer combined with LINQ `Except` or `Intersect` added additional overhead compared to my own basic implementation of just iterating through the list comparing everything with everything?*

Lastly, a full reproducible example below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StackOverflow();
    }

    private static void StackOverflow()
    {
        var firstEmployeeList = CreateEmployeeList(5000);
        var secondEmployeeList = CreateEmployeeList(4000);

        var intersectingEmployeesManual = new List<Employee>();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        //Intersecting employees - comparing predefined property
        sw.Start();
        foreach (var employee in firstEmployeeList)
        {
            if (secondEmployeeList.Any(x => x.ReferenceCode == employee.ReferenceCode))
                intersectingEmployeesManual.Add(employee);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Intersecting Employees Manual: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        intersectingEmployeesManual.Clear();
        sw.Reset();

        //Intersecting employees - comparing dynamic property
        sw.Start();
        foreach (var employee in firstEmployeeList)
        {
            if (secondEmployeeList.Any(x => x.GetType()
                .GetProperty("ReferenceCode").GetValue(x)
                .Equals(employee.GetType().GetProperty("ReferenceCode").GetValue(employee))))
                intersectingEmployeesManual.Add(employee);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Intersecting Employees Manual (dynamic property): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        //Delta Employees - comparing predefined property
        var deltaEmployeesManual = new List<Employee>();
        sw.Start();
        foreach (var employee in firstEmployeeList)
        {
            if (secondEmployeeList.All(x => x.ReferenceCode != employee.ReferenceCode))
                deltaEmployeesManual.Add(employee);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Delta Employees Manual: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        deltaEmployeesManual.Clear();

        //Delta Employees - comparing dynamic property
        sw.Start();
        foreach (var employee in firstEmployeeList)
        {
            if (secondEmployeeList
                .All(x => !x.GetType().GetProperty("ReferenceCode").GetValue(x)
                .Equals(employee.GetType().GetProperty("ReferenceCode").GetValue(employee))))
                deltaEmployeesManual.Add(employee);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Delta Employees Manual (dynamic property): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        //Intersecting employees Linq - dynamic property
        sw.Start();
        var intersectingEmployeesLinq = firstEmployeeList
            .Intersect(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerDynamic("ReferenceCode")).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Intersecting Employees Linq (dynamic property): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        //Intersecting employees Linq - manual property
        sw.Start();
        var intersectingEmployeesLinqManual = firstEmployeeList
            .Intersect(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerManual()).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Intersecting Employees Linq (manual property): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        //Delta employees Linq - dynamic property
        sw.Start();
        var deltaEmployeesLinq = firstEmployeeList
            .Except(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerDynamic("ReferenceCode")).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Delta Employees Linq (dynamic property): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        //Delta employees Linq - manual property
        sw.Start();
        var deltaEmployeesLinqManual = firstEmployeeList
            .Except(secondEmployeeList, new EmployeeComparerManual()).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Delta Employees Linq (manual property): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static List<Employee> CreateEmployeeList(int numberToCreate)
    {
        var employeList = new List<Employee>();
        for (var i = 0; i < numberToCreate; i++)
        {
            employeList.Add(new Employee
            {
                ReferenceCode = i.ToString()
            });
        }
        return employeList;
    }

    internal class Employee
    {
        public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeComparerDynamic : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
    {
        string PropertyNameToCompare { get; set; }
        public EmployeeComparerDynamic(string propertyNameToCompare)
        {
            PropertyNameToCompare = propertyNameToCompare;
        }

        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return y.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetValue(y) != null 
                && x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetValue(x)
                .Equals(y.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetValue(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee x) 
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + x.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare).GetValue(x).GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeComparerManual : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
    {
        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return y.ReferenceCode != null
                   && x.ReferenceCode.Equals(y.ReferenceCode);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee x)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + x.ReferenceCode.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

So with the help of the suggestion to use delegates in equality comparer and the point that I was not calculating hashcode properly in the dynamic equality comparer, I was able to conclude the following:

- Reflection does add overhead, but my issue with LINQ `Except` and `Intersect` performing poorly was because of dynamic equality comparer and the fact that I was calculating hashcode using the `GetHasCode()` on the property rather than on the property's value.
- Using delegate equality does bring back the performance and the usage syntax remains neat and concise.

I implemented the below equality comparer now:

```
public static class Compare
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<TSource> By<TSource, TIdentity>(Func<TSource, TIdentity> identitySelector)
    {
        return new DelegateComparer<TSource, TIdentity>(identitySelector);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectBy<T, TIdentity>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, TIdentity> identitySelector)
    {
        return source.Intersect(second, By(identitySelector));
    }

    private class DelegateComparer<T, TIdentity> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, TIdentity> identitySelector;

        public DelegateComparer(Func<T, TIdentity> identitySelector)
        {
            this.identitySelector = identitySelector;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return Equals(identitySelector(x), identitySelector(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return identitySelector(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Which works nicely with the usage syntax being:

```
        var intersectingEmployeesDelegate = firstEmployeeList
            .IntersectBy(secondEmployeeList, x => x.ReferenceCode).ToList();
```

The only outstanding question that I have remaining is whether there is a neat way to call this comparison on all properties on a given type.

My initial implementation was similar to below:

```
        foreach (var pInfo in typeof(Employee).GetProperties())
        {
            var intersectingEmployees = firstEmployeeList
                .Intersect(secondEmployeeList, 
                new EmployeeComparerDynamic(pInfo.Name)).ToList();
        }
```

Any ideas if similar is achievable using the delegate comparer?

Comment: That comprarer is a performance killer, you are retrieving the `Type` and the `PropertyInfo` each time you are going to compare an employee to other. Cache that data, reflection is heavy, so the more you cache/reduce the reflection operations the better it will work.

Comment: Using Refelection to get a value is slow. There is just no way around that. The default behavior for ValueType.Equals (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx) is to either do a "byte by byte" comparision or refeleciton to itterate over the fields. Both approaches are **glacially slow**, and you should provide a proper overload. Reflection is just unsuited for bulk work.

Comment: Honestly I am confused why you are using Reflection here. If you want to have multiple ways to sort any class, just provide multiple sorters. Most types come out with having only a "default Order" from the IComparabile implementation. But not all of them. usr also pointed out the option to provide the Comperer as Delegate. If you go that route, the comparer can even be a anonymous function.

Comment: @Christopher this isn't really about sorting, these lists of objects would actually be acquired from different databases, then normalized into the same model with various properties and then compared to work out the difference and similarities.

Comment: Generally strong typisation is your biggest friend. Never avoid it, always embrace it. If you get data from a weakly type sources, ExpandoObject is there for you. Basically it is just a `Dictionary<string, object>` with some Syntax sugar to make it appear you are using properties. Once you have the data in ExpandoObjects, you can translate it to some strongly typed custom class. And then just work with those.

Comment: Your EmployeeComparerDynamic.GetHashCode returns the same value every time. It "works", but is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek why would it return the same value every time? It should be different hash if the property value is different?

Comment: You get hash from the property itself, not its value. Add GetValue(x) before the GetHashCode.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Yep, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use reflection to get all properties, you have to use solution proposed by usr. You have to construct and compile expression tree into delegate and use it as an parameter for constructor of the comparer. The code may look like:

```
public static IEqualityComparer<T> GetComparer<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    Type tT = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(tT);
    MemberExpression memberExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, propertyInfo);
    LambdaExpression lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(memberExpr, paramExpr);

    Type tQ = memberExpr.Type;
    Type te = typeof(DelegateEqualityComparer<,>);
    Type te2 = te.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { tT, tQ });
    ConstructorInfo ci = te2.GetConstructors()[0];

    Object i = ci.Invoke(new object[] { lambdaExpr.Compile() });

    return (IEqualityComparer<T>)i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can pass a delegate to the comparer?

```
new DelegateEqualityComparer<Employee>(e => e.ReferenceCode)
```

If you want to base this on strings you can compile a delegate from an expression tree. Do this once in the constructor.

Comment: I think it would be nice to be able to compare int properties too, without converting to string.

Comment: @usr Thank you for the suggestion, I have edited my question with an implementaiton of DelegateEqualityComparer, perhaps you have an idea how to iteratively evaluate properties on a given type?